# Can Principal Components have unit length?

Tags: pca

Consider the following pieces of code and their associated outputs.

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

data = X
n_components = data.shape[1]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(data)
data = scaler.transform(data)

pca = PCA(n_components=n_components, random_state=4)
pca = pca.fit(data)
pca.singular_values_
pca.components_
```

```
array([20.92306556, 11.7091661 ,  4.69185798,  1.76273239])

array([[ 0.52106591, -0.26934744,  0.5804131 ,  0.56485654],
       [ 0.37741762,  0.92329566,  0.02449161,  0.06694199],
       [-0.71956635,  0.24438178,  0.14212637,  0.63427274],
       [-0.26128628,  0.12350962,  0.80144925, -0.52359713]])
```

```py
for row in pca.components_:
    print(np.linalg.norm(row, ord=2))
```

```
0.9999999999999997
0.9999999999999994
1.0
1.0
```

I noticed that the length (=euclidean norm) of all my principal components is 1. Why is that? I thought that the principal components are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and do not necessarily have unit length.

Update: Added the singular values. They are indeed all different. However, when applying PCA in order to transform data, they are not used. See relevant code here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/dfc5e16066b3a3bbf34238cc0f67639d0965f1a8/sklearn/decomposition/_base.py#L129 Only `self.components_` are used, which all have length one.

Comment: You can multiply those vectors by anything you want to ease their interpretation.  The interpretation won't change.  The unit length convention is just that - a convention.  You could just as well impose the convention that the maximum value is 100 (which actually may make interpretation easier).

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors can have length 1 (they can have arbitrary magnitude). Look into the corresponding eigenvalues to check their weighting on the PCA solution.